# Nail Gun types (nomenclature)?

Tags: doors, nails

I would like a nail gun for nailing

1. door trim
2. hardy board panel

Do I need two different nail guns?  If yes, what are the two different types?  I need the correct names of the types (nomenclature) so that I can search online & purchase.  Thank you

Comment: I've not used a nail gun on "hardy" (or cement) board.  For door framing, however, you want a "finish nailer".  These use headless nail and "set" them below the wood surface.

Comment: Hardy board would need screwed on  OR to be Pre-drilled with pilot holes for nailing and using a nail gun would be very difficult to get the nail in the pre-drilled hole.  All about nail guns - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=all+about+nail+guns

Comment: For clarity, are you talking about Hardie siding, or cement board that goes in a bathroom? BTW, the answer to #1 is usually an 18 gauge nail gun. (Though there are arguments for/against a 16 gauge as well.)